# React Routes and Components prop mix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following line of code:

```
<Route path="/users/:id" exact ><User url={structure.users} /></Route>
```

In User component I do the following:

```
function User(props, {match}) {


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(match);
        console.log(props);
    }, [props]);
    // ...
}
```

I removed a bit of the code because I only want to show what is necessary but here I see that match is undefined but it should have match.params.id from the link. How can I achieve this so i can make the full url with the url with the attached id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React components receive only a single props object argument.

Use the `Route`'s `render` prop so you can pass the route props on to the component.

```
<Route
  path="/users/:id"
  exact
  render={routeProps => <User url={structure.users} {...routeProps} />}
/>
```

Alternatively you can use the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) React hook to access `match.params` of the current `Route`.

```
import { ...., useParams, .... } from 'react-router-dom';

function User(props) {
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(props);
  }, [props]);
  // ...
}
```